# Parameter of src returns undefined type in javascript. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, src

I have error that `Cannot read property 'src' of undefined`
Code is it-

```
tokens = tokenize("/",document.images[idx].src);
```

I have to use only javascript, and I need linked filename of `images`. Is there any alternative of this code? So i used `src`, but `src` returns `undefined` now.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `document.images[index].src` — if `document.images[index]` is a valid image, then it will have a `.src` property.

What the browser is telling you here is that for your particular value of `idx` there is no such image on the page. Perhaps `idx` is `100` and you have fewer images than that — or perhaps `idx` is something nonsensical like `-5`.

Use a valid index and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if idx variable value is valid.
2. Also there is a dependency of where you are running the code. I.e. may be you have proper value in idx. But by the time the script is running the image has not been loaded to DOM. Hence check for that. So try to call the function when all the images are loaded and DOM is ready. To check how many images are loaded check for document.images.length just before the line you are executing.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Images were not loaded to DOM, so sorry to ask more how can i load images to DOM? isn't enough to use HTML tag in <BODY> like <img src='1.gif'>?

Comment: its not that images are not loaded, it's just images are not loaded when that piece of code is being executed

Comment: You have to wait for images to be loaded. Check my answer to check DOM is ready or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067977/setting-onclick-function-in-external-javascript/36068319#36068319